# html textual link hover background image

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

There is a background inside the div. Then I would write a list of links, which then pass over the background image, but it not seems to work.

If the link is located above the background mage, hovering the mouse on that, I do not get the underline of the text as for all other links that are not above the image background.

This is my code:

```
<div style="min-height:200px;">
  <div class="backgroundImg"
      style="background: url(/my/url.png) no-repeat; height:140px; width: 140px;position: absolute;>
  </div> 
  <div style="z-index:30">
    <a href="#">My link here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for my English, the concept is really easy to understand but hard to explain ... I hope to be able to explain.

Thanks to all, Danilo

---

Edit:

I found the error ... if you do not use "absolute" propriety in both div, z-index non work.

Thanks for the suggestions! ;-)

Comment: Try to post an example on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - it will be easier to understand what you are trying to do!

Comment: Please post your own answer and accept it, so that the question will be made closed. It might also earn you a few upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error ... if you do not use "absolute" propriety in both div, z-index non work.

Thanks for the suggestions! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand, but I'll try:

1) If you have a link above the div with background, try with a different value of z-index on the link or setting a paddin on the link, so the div goes down and you'll see the underline.

2) If you want to have a list over the image background, insert it IN the div with background.

Comment: I am in the first case. With the z-index does not work. What does "setting at paddin"?

Comment: sorry, it was "setting a padding-bottom" on the link: with this property the div with background will goes down and you will see the underline.